does arm MTE tag exists in an stage-2 IPA?
Does IPA have Top Bits Ignore(TBI)? In the process of checking MTE tag, an VA is translate to PA and check the tag. I am wondering if there exists stage-2 translation, will the tag remained in the IPA's top bits?
I find there is no TBI config option in the VTCR_EL2 register, but TCR has.
